# is it possible to static link the rust application when using apple M1

Tags: rust, arm, static-linking

Recently I am learning rust static linking, now I found a issue that it seems impossible to static linking the rust application when using M1 chip. I have read the official document from here https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html and only found this platform:

```
aarch64-apple-darwin
```

but it seems not a static link binary option(it may contains musl), is it possible to static link with M1 chip in 2023.06?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reference to MUSL.  Are you trying to cross-compile a static binary for `aarch64-apple-darwin` from Linux?

Comment: I do not need cross compile, I just need to create a static linking binary file. it is ok only running with M1 chip.@eggyal I just need a independent binary file.